# Understand Hadoop wordcount example

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce

the sample code is here
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount

I understand the logic, however, I noticed that in the main function, it only specifies the input and output paths, however, it never specifies what is the key and the value.

How does the map and reduce function figure that out?

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you understand that the Mapper and Reducer are in the form Key1, Value1, Key2, Value2 and that Key1 and Value1 are the input key-value types and Key2 and Value2 are the output types, I'll explain the rest.

In the main function you'll see a line which says,

```
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
```

Now, this is what decides how the input file is read. If you'll look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/TextInputFormat.java) of `TextInputFormat` you'll see (in its line 41) that it uses the `LineRecordReader` ([source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-737/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/LineRecordReader.java#LineRecordReader)) which breaks the file into key-value pairs. Here the line offset is set as key and the line itself as value.

But like you said, this is not done automatically. You can control this behavior by writing your own custom **input format** and **record reader** classes.

Hope this clears up your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

The interfaces for the `Mapper` and `Reducer` classes enforce the types on the `map` and `reduce` functions:

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    ...
}
```

and

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    ...
}
```

They are both of the form `K1, V1, K2, V2` where `K1, V1` are the input key-value types and `K2, V2` are the output types.

Comment: I know those are kvkv types, however, the only input I can find is the filename, it seems like the "opening the file, read a byte/word/line, choose the word to be key/value" part is done automatically. So that looks weird to me.